# Ember switching between templates in {output}

Tags: html, templates, ember.js

I'm building my first ember app which has CRUD properties. Part of my index.html code looks like this-

```
<script type = "text/x-handlebars" id = "settings">

<table>
  {{#each setting in controller}}
    <tr>
 <td>
      <h2>{{setting.name}}</h2>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>{{#link-to "setting" setting}}More Details..{{/link-to}}</td>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
</table>

{{outlet}}

</script>

<script type = "text/x-handlebars" id = "setting">
{{#if deleteMode}}
<div class="confirm-box">
  <h4>Really?</h4>
  <button {{action "confirmDelete"}}> yes </button>
  <button {{action "cancelDelete"}}> no </button>
</div>
{{/if}}
<div class="col-xs-6">
<h4>{{name}}</h4>
<h4>{{address_line1}}</h4>
<h4>{{address_line2}}</h4>
<h4>{{address_city}}</h4>
<h4>{{address_state}}</h4>
<h4>{{address_zip}}</h4>
<h4>{{address_country}}</h4>

<button {{action "edit"}}>Edit</button>
</div>

<div class = "col-xs-6">
{{outlet}}
</div>
</script>

<script type = "text/x-handlebars" id = "setting/edit">


<div class="input-group">
  <h5>Name:</h5>
  {{input value=name}}

   <h5>Address:</h5>
  {{input value=address_line1}}

  {{input value=address_line2}}

   <h5>City:</h5>
  {{input value=address_city}}

   <h5>State:</h5>
  {{input value=address_state}}

   <h5>ZIP:</h5>
  {{input value=address_zip}}

   <h5>Country:</h5>
  {{input value=address_country}}


  <button {{action "save"}}> Save </button>
</div>

</script>
```

When I click on the `edit` button in the `setting` template, the `setting/edit` template with an edit form opens in the `{outlet}`of the `setting` template. I'm wondering how I would go about getting the `setting/edit` template to replace the `setting` template in the `settings` template's `{outlet}` so that they don't appear on the same page? New to ember dev and somewhat confused, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember always routes to leaf route. when you are on `settingRoute`(means only setting template is rendered) in reality your leaf route is `settingIndexRoute` and in `{outlet}` of `setting` route `setting/index` template is rendered,which is generated by ember when it found out that you have not specified index template. so when you click on edit, `setting/edit` will replace `setting/index` template. so I would suggest that you move your `setting` template's content in `setting/index`.